# Google voice application not running on other devices

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I had deployed my first trivia app and a email regarding the release says that my app's version is approved and is now in the process of being deployed to production on Feb 20 of 2020, and now when I checked this app on other devices via invocation and also by typing its name(Mr. Trex) in explore section I wasn't able to find it where on the other hand its running fine on my devices(due to my google account).[image of version release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/putDk.png)
Here I am also attaching a link to the google [application](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/0000009009b862d4?hl=en&source=web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Action name is fairly difficult to pronounce. Even seeing the listing, it isn't clear if it should be pronounced "t-rex" or "trecks" or something else. Looking at [my Assistant activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=31) it also seems to have trouble with the "Mr" part. What it has heard includes:

- Talk to mister tree rex
- Talk to mister treks
- Talk to mr. Athletics
- Talk to Mr Trex
- Talk to Mr. Krabs

Your best bet is to try and change the name to something that is clearer or more obvious to pronounce.